# Mixed native and managed code heap corruption

Tags: dllimport, heap-corruption

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and importing a native C++ DLL into C#. When I simply call the functions from the DLL and do nothing else in my C# code everything works as it should, but when I start doing other things in the front end I get the error:

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' has detected a problem in 'D:\Jeff\4YP\ImageViewerApp\ImageViewerApp\bin\Debug\ImageViewerApp.vshost.exe'.
>   Additional Information: The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x6b4f8127, on thread 0x1460. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.

I believe it is a heap corruption problem. I have tried playing around with the code in the DLL (which is basically exporting a class) and have managed to get the program to run when I remove all lines which assign to (non-pointer) class variables. But pointers and local function variables seem not to lead to the corruption. And rather strangely, there appears to be no corruption for the particular cases of class variables of type int, float, double, but it does occur for my user-defined types and bool (I haven't tried all types).

What could cause this rather confusing scenario?

Here is the code from my C++ DLL:

```
#pragma once

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "GlobalClassifier.h"

const int frameRate = 33;
const int jointFeaturesCount = 9;

namespace MyKinectDll
{
    typedef struct vector
    {
        public:
            float x;
            float y;
            float z;
    } VECTOR;

    [event_receiver(native)]
    class __declspec(dllexport) MyKinect
    {
        public:
            MyKinect(void)
            {
                //Fails when these lines are included:
                //initialise hand positions
                leftHandPos.x = 0;
                leftHandPos.y = 0;
                leftHandPos.z = 0;
                rightHandPos.x = 0;
                rightHandPos.y = 0;
                rightHandPos.z = 0;

                bGotNewGesture = false;
                latestGesture = CClassifier::GestureType::Left_Circular;

                //It doesn't fail when these lines are included:

                //Create sensor
                mySensor = new CNuiSensor();

                //Create and initialise classifier
                myClassifier = new CGlobalClassifier(mySensor, frameRate, jointFeaturesCount);
                myClassifier->Initialise("model.dat");

                //Initialise sensor
                mySensor->Nui_Init();
            };

            ~MyKinect(void)
            {
            };

        private:
            CGlobalClassifier *myClassifier;
            CNuiSensor *mySensor;
            bool bGotNewGesture;
            CClassifier::GestureType latestGesture;
            VECTOR leftHandPos;
            VECTOR rightHandPos;
        };
    };
```

And here is the C# import wrapper:

```
struct UnmanWrap
{
    //Import constructor
    [DllImport("MyKinectDll.dll", EntryPoint = "??0MyKinect@MyKinectDll@@QAE@XZ",
               CallingConvention = CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
    public static extern void Constructor(ref UnmanWrap t);
}

public class MyKinectWrap
{
    private UnmanWrap unman;

    public MyKinectWrap()
    {
        //Add a path to location of the DLL file.
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH","D:\\Jeff\\4YP\\MyKinectDll2\\Release");

        this.unman = new UnmanWrap();
        UnmanWrap.Constructor(ref this.unman);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's the way bad C++ code crashes.  Or a bad pinvoke declaration.  There's nothing in your question that helps us help you write good code.

Comment: Ok, if you would be so good as to tell me what is bad about my code :)